# How to use #if directives in C#(3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

I just found two piece of code

```
#if CONSOLE // defined by the console version using 
ournamespace.FactoryInitializer;
#endif
```

and

```
#if _NET_1_1
                    log4net.Config.DOMConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new System.IO.FileInfo(s) );
#else
                    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new System.IO.FileInfo(s) );
#endif
```

Can any one please tell me with a running sample( please provide a simple one) what is the significance of those  code snippets and when and how to use those?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure. These refer to *conditional compilation symbols* which can be defined at compile-time and which control what code is actually built. Here's an example:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
#if FOO
        Console.WriteLine("FOO was defined");
#endif        

#if BAR
        Console.WriteLine("BAR was defined");
#endif                
    }
}
```

If you compile this with

```
csc Test.cs
```

It won't print anything. If you compile it with

```
csc Test.cs /D:FOO
```

then it will print "FOO was defined" - and obviously the same is true for BAR.

Note that these aren't the same as C++ macros - a symbol is either defined or not; it doesn't have a "replacement value" as such.

In Visual Studio, you specify which symbols should be defined in the Build tab of the project properties. Additionally, at the very start of the file you can explicitly define and undefine symbols:

```
#define FOO
#undef BAR
```

This can be important when calling methods decorated with [`ConditionalAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) - such calls are ignored by the compiler if the appropriate symbol isn't defined. So if you wanted to make sure that all your [`Debug.Print`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.print.aspx) calls came through even if you hadn't defined the DEBUG symbol for the rest of the project, you could use:

```
#define DEBUG
...
Debug.Print("Foo");
```

Personally, I don't use all this very much. Aside from anything else, it makes it easier to understand the code if you know that it will all be compiled and run at execution time.

EDIT: Just to clarify a little on terminology - `#if`, `#line`, `#pragma` etc are all preprocessor directives; FOO and BAR (in this case) are the conditional compilation symbols.

Comment: I thought the term was "Preprocessor Directives"? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: @Oded: #if is a preprocessor directive, but FOO and BAR themselves are conditional compilation symbols. The term "preprocessor directive" is broader, including #pragma, #line etc as well.

Answer (score 2):

They're used for [conditional compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691099(VS.71).aspx).

If CONSOLE (known as a conditional compilation symbol) is defined for the first example with `#define CONSOLE`, the code within #if CONSOLE and #endif will be compiled and built into the assembly, otherwise the compiler ignores the code within them.

Undefining a conditional compile symbol is via #undef e.g `#undef CONSOLE`. The [language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691095(VS.71).aspx) also states :

> There is no requirement that
>   conditional compilation symbols be
>   explicitly declared before they are
>   referenced in pre-processing
>   expressions. Instead, undeclared
>   symbols are simply undefined and thus
>   have the value false.

Answer (score 1):

Those are called [preprocessor directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha(VS.71).aspx). Quote from the docs:

> '#if' lets you begin a conditional directive, 
>   testing a symbol or symbols
>   to see if they evaluate to true. If
>   they do evaluate to true, the compiler
>   evaluates all the code between the #if
>   and the next directive.

So basically when you compile your program with [/define:symbol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx) switch it will either evaluate the if statement or not. For example:

```
csc foo.cs /define:DEBUG
```

allows you to define the DEBUG directive and enter the `#if DEBUG` branch. Remember that contrary to the [if](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h(VS.71).aspx) statement those are purely compile time and the body of the else statement won't even be included in your compiled assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Your project can have multiple configurations, the most common are Debug and Release.
In Debug mode you can output debug strings, do additional checking etc.

For example:

```
void a(int x){    
    #if DEBUG
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("a("+x+")");
    #endif
    //Do stuff.
}
```

You can define directives project-wide in the project's properties and make debug/release builds, or you could make an application that uses different libraries for some output (OpenGL/XNA). Or as you have, `#if _NET_1_1` checks if a symbol `_NET_1_1` is defined, assuming that .NET FX 1.1 is used, and uses proper classes, so you can target multiple framework versions in multiple project configurations.